# ssh using R system() command

Tags: linux, r, ssh

When I try to connect computer A to computer B using ssh and R's `system()` command, I get an error:

```
system('ssh root@Bs-ip-address')

ssh_askpass: exec(rpostback-askpass): No such file or directory
Host key verification failed.
lost connection
```

But if I enter the command in quotes into my Linux terminal (`ssh root@Bs-ip-address`) it works fine (ssh keys are set up for the correct user). How can I connect properly using R's `system()` command? Or can you suggest a better way to connect?

It might have something to do with needing to enter 'yes' to the following prompt that arises within Linux:

```
The authenticity of host Bs-ip-address (Bs-ip-address) cant be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is unique-fingerprint.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?
```

After I enter 'yes' once in a putty session, the R `system()` command above will work. But I don't want to have to enter into putty each time. (As a side note, I'm creating a number of identical Digital Ocean instances with pre-set ssh keys, and trying to connect to them from R, so entering a putty session each time for each new instance is not a workable option.) Can you send a 'yes' command using `system()`?

Comment: See Jeroen Ooms' R package for SSH: https://github.com/jeroenooms/ssh

Comment: Thanks, did not investigate this package, but it looks promising! The accepted solution below was everything I needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could automate that acceptance (caveat: you have to be *sure* that the machines you're about to access are trusted!).

If the hosts have rsa keys, for instance, you can do:

```
system( 'ssh-keyscan  -t rsa Bs-ip-address  >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts' )
```

HIH.

Comment: Works as you indicate.

Comment: sweet :) ... pleased to hear.

Comment: I'm using Shiny submit button to connect to remote server ( via ssh) and submit a slurm job, but the job does not execute. Basic shell commands work, but not HPC specific commands.  I have posted a Q on poist community https://community.rstudio.com/t/running-commands-on-remote-hpc-server-via-r-shiny-ui/179989/5