# R - Connect via ssh and execute a command

Tags: r, linux, bash, networking, ssh

I would like to connect via ssh to certain equipment in a network.

The requisites are:

1. It must run a command and capture the output of the ssh session in R (or in bash, or any other programming language, but I would prefer it in R language)
2. It must enter a plain-text password (as this equipment hasn't been accessed before, and can't be changed with a rsa keypair), so the `ssh.utils` package doesn't meet this requirement
3. `sshpass` can't be used, as I have noticed that it doesn't work for some devices I tested.

I've read all this posts but I can't find an effective way to perform it: [link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17347450/how-do-you-connect-to-a-remote-server-with-ssh-in-r), [link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19765138/r-language-open-ssh-connection), [link 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32173180/ssh-using-r-system-command), [link 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31168907/authenticating-in-browser-trough-r-with-ssh)

I know the requirements are hard to accomplish, but thank you for your effort!

**EDIT:**

Sorry if I didn't make myself understandable. I mean I work locally in R and I want to connect to +3000 devices in all of my network via ssh. It is Ubiquiti equipment, and the only open ports are 80 and 22.

If ssh doesn't work, I will use the `RSelenium` package for R and extract info from port 80. But first I will try with ssh pory 22 as it is a lot more efficient than opening an emulated browser.

The big problem in all these Ubiquiti equipment is that they have a password to log in. That's why requisite No.2 is needed. When I must enter a server that I know, I spend time setting up the rsa keypair so that I don't have to enter a password everytime I connect to a specific server, but it's impossible (or at least, for me it's impossible) to configure all +3000 Ubiquiti equipment with these keypairs.

That's why I don't use snmp, for example, as this equipment maybe they have it activated or not, or the snmp configuration is mistaken. I mean, I have to use something that's activated by default, and in a way, ordered. And only port 80 and port 22 are activated and I know all the user's and password's equipment.

And `sshpass` is an utility in UNIX/Linux  [like this link explains](https://www.google.es/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0ahUKEwiUzYi-kJXKAhWKOhQKHZj0AmAQFgggMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.cyberciti.biz%2Ffaq%2Fnoninteractive-shell-script-ssh-password-provider%2F&usg=AFQjCNGC5xcTXPz12sOBbZ5ubfOprw7mXQ&sig2=xl2W15FEQwLX11vv4VC7AQ&cad=rja) that works for servers but doesn't work for Ubiquiti equipment, as long as I've tested it. So I can't use it.

The command I need to extract the output from is `mca-status`. Simply by entering that into the console makes it print some stats I will like to get from the Ubiquiti equipment.

Correct me, please, if I am wrong in something I've posted. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I solved it using the `rPython` package and the python's `paramiko` module, as there was no way to do it purely via R.

```
library(rPython)
python.exec(python.code = c("import paramiko", 
                            "ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()",
                            "ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())",
                            sprintf('ssh.connect("%s", username="USER", password="PASSWORD") ', IP),
                            'stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command("mca-status")',
                            'stats = stdout.readlines()'))
```

Comment: I'm trying to do something similar. Shh to remote host and run commands via R / Shiny interface. Basic commands work, but when I try to execute HPC specific commands like module load or try to submit a slurm job using Shiny UI interface via a submit button it does not work. I'm trying to build a dashboard in shiny that would allow to  submit slurm jobs, monitor progress and view results

Answer (score 1):

I think you have this wrong. I also have no idea what you are trying to say in point 2, and I have not idea what point 3 is supposed to say.

Now: `ssh` is a *authentication* mechanism allowing you (trusted) access to another machine and the ability to run a command.  This can be as simple as

```
edd@max:~$ ssh bud Rscript -e '2+2'
[1] 4
edd@max:~$
```

where I invoke `R` (or rather, `Rscript`) on the machine 'bud' (my desktop) from a session on the machine 'max' (my server).  That command could be *anything* including something which writes to temporary or permanent files.  You can then retrieve those files via `scp`.

Authentication is handled independently -- on Unix we often use `ssh-agent` which run in the background and against you authenticate on login.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Please see my edited question, if that makes you understand the problem better.

Comment: Hm. You may need to write soemthing yourself, maybe calling `mca-status` and ingesting its output. I am not aware of anything existing.